# Make AppBarLayout respond to scrolling in WebView

Tags: android, xml, webview

In the design support Library (from I/O) Google introduced the AppBarLayout. I'm trying to make the Toolbar animate out of the screen when the user scrolls through a website in a WebView in a Fragment. It does work when I put my WebView element inside a NestedScrollView, but that makes scrolling through the WebView buggy and makes pinch-to-zoom impossible. 
How can I make the AppBarLayout respond (animate away when scrolling down, return when scrolling up, just like in NestedScrollView) to the WebView? These are my XML files:
The main layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/main_coordinatorlayout">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewPager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_autorenew" />
```

The code of my fragment containing the webview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any progress on this? Also looking to hook up a webview with a toolbar.

Comment: No I'm sorry, I have given up on this for now. If you can find a solution, I would love to hear it, because I am still interested.

Comment: I needed something like this too. While searching online I found this [github project](https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout). You just need the `NestedWebView` class. It works pretty well, although the scrolling doesn't feel very smooth.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @[torque203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2323637/torque203) for providing this answer. I'm reposting this to gather more attention to it.

You can extend webview and implement NestedScrollingChild. For example, you can use the [NestedWebView](https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/takahirom/webview_in_coodinator_layout/NestedWebView.java) object found in [this Github project](https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout).

From there on, you can act like it's a normal View that supports Nested Scrolling, like a RecyclerView:

```
<your.package.name.NestedWebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

In my use case, this worked fine.

Again, credits to @[torque203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2323637/torque203) for finding this Github project.

Comment: NestedWebView did not seem to work properly when I tested it with a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Most serious issue is that pinch zoom does not work properly at all; it jumps away to a different point on the page after every pinch zoom. Additional issues are that the app bar scrolling animation is choppy, and the class doesn't seem to track the origin correctly for nested scroll dispatches. (I tested with support 23.2.0 and 23.3.0.)

Comment: @LorneLaliberte I added a pull request to the [github](https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout) project mentioned in the answer that fixes the jump during multi-touch gestures like pinch to zoom.

Comment: @torque203, What if the webview itself has some scrolling content inside it? Like say, it has a dropdown which scrolls up/down. This isn't working.

Comment: FYI, there's an alternate library here that does the same thing : https://github.com/tobiasrohloff/NestedScrollWebView

Answer (score 3):

@Rick de Vries the simplest way without any third party library is that
after AppBarLayout make a NestedScrollView having the child as WebView only. Below is an example for the same -

```
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Things placed inside CoordinatorLayout must be designed and implemented to work with it or it will not coordinate with any other sibling views. But well ... Toolbar is not designed for that. AppBarLayout is just an component that is prepared to make Toolbar works perfectly with CoordinatorLayout.

LinearLayout is not designed to work with CoordinatorLayout.It is for more easy, you just need to add an attribute to the LinearLayout telling its scroll behavior

```
<LinearLayout
...
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
...
>
```

you can try make AppBarLayout respond to the WebView by this

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

since ScrollView is now a direct child of CoordinatorLayout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

ScrollView was not designed to work with CoordinatorLayout (again). You need to use the another one, NestedScrollView, provided in Android Support Library v4, which is designed to work with CoordinatorLayout since born.

And with the same reason, please note that the classic ListView doesn't work with CoordinatorLayout as well. Only RecyclerView works.

Comment: Thanks foryour answer, but as I mentioned in my starting post, doing so does hide the Toolbar when I scroll, but it also makes scrolling buggy/unpredictable and it makes pinch-to-zoom impossible. I'm looking for a solution so I can still pinch-to-zoom. Can you suggest any? Because this makes it impossible, but still thanks for your answer.

Comment: The key for me was to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to my layout immediately following the app bar layout, but to completely REMOVE the `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` attribute from my Toolbar. This allowed scrolling without any change in toolbar height and without any issue with web view content height/scroll view wrapping.