# WebView in NestedScrollView gives Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) code -6 RenderThread

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, sigabrt

I have an activity with a ViewPager and TabLayout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/item_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/item_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

One of the Fragments is a WebView. In order to have the Toolbar hide when the WebView is scrolled, I have the WebView in a NestedScrollView.

Prior to adding the NestedScrollView, the app worked fine, but it didn't hide the Toolbar.

Now, as soon as the WebView finished loading, the app closes without a Java stack trace.

The Fragment layout is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/browser_root"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/browser_loading_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/browser_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible">

        </WebView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

When something is to be loaded,  mWebView.loadUrl is called. The WebView has a client so that when the page load is finished the Spinner visibility is set to gone and the WebView is made visible.

The Android Monitor reads :

```
10-25 15:22:12.111 3871-3871/com.tpb.hn I/Browser: loadURL: WebView loading
10-25 15:22:12.113 3871-3871/com.tpb.hn I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
10-25 15:22:12.118 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-25 15:22:12.118 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1

                                                          [ 10-25 15:22:12.118  3871: 3911 D/         ]
                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7ffeeca88c00, tid 3911
10-25 15:22:12.126 3871-3936/com.tpb.hn E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
10-25 15:22:12.136 3871-3936/com.tpb.hn I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es

                                                             [ 10-25 15:22:12.138  3871: 3936 D/         ]
                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7ffeeb7fe080, tid 3936
10-25 15:22:12.219 3871-3871/com.tpb.hn W/chromium: [WARNING:shell.cc(299)] Instance: exe:chrome attempting to register an instance for a process it created for target: exe:chrome_renderer without the mojo:shell{client_process} capability class.
10-25 15:22:12.317 3871-3871/com.tpb.hn W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 3871
10-25 15:22:12.317 3871-3871/com.tpb.hn D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
10-25 15:22:12.418 3871-3876/com.tpb.hn I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=24KB, data=29KB
10-25 15:22:12.419 3871-3876/com.tpb.hn I/art: After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=29KB
10-25 15:22:12.419 3871-3876/com.tpb.hn I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
10-25 15:22:12.635 3871-3871/com.tpb.hn I/HNLoader: onResponse: [I@842b545
10-25 15:22:12.635 3871-3871/com.tpb.hn I/ContentAdapter: IdLoadDone: 
10-25 15:22:13.673 3871-3876/com.tpb.hn I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=55KB, data=61KB
10-25 15:22:13.673 3871-3876/com.tpb.hn I/art: After code cache collection, code=55KB, data=61KB
10-25 15:22:13.673 3871-3876/com.tpb.hn I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
10-25 15:22:13.765 3871-3871/com.tpb.hn W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
10-25 15:22:13.766 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_VALUE
10-25 15:22:13.766 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn A/OpenGLRenderer: GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/BakedOpRenderer.cpp:66

                                                          --------- beginning of crash
10-25 15:22:13.788 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
10-25 15:22:13.788 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
10-25 15:22:13.788 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn W/google-breakpad: 1.0
10-25 15:22:13.788 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn W/google-breakpad: 1
10-25 15:22:13.788 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn W/google-breakpad: f3e1957e-ea20-4058-8e10-b7e303fde16a
10-25 15:22:13.788 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
10-25 15:22:13.788 3871-3911/com.tpb.hn A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3911 (RenderThread)

                                                [ 10-25 15:22:13.788  1181: 1181 W/         ]
                                                debuggerd: handling request: pid=3871 uid=10066 gid=10066 tid=3911
```

loadUrl is when the WebView starts loading

I have read posts about Fatal signal 6 code -6, but none have offered a solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit- I removed the default invisibility of the WebView, and the code changing it, and got a much larger trace with more detail.

I can't post it here as the post ends up at 59000 characters, but it is now on PasteBin [Here](http://pastebin.com/NKMV45zz)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. In my case, the problem was with this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}
```

I removed this line of code, and my app stoped crashing. I faced with this issue on Android N.
BTW `Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if your Target API level is >=14` and i think this  line of code is redundant.

Comment: Same here. It was causing only one test device and now gone!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way to get the behaviour I want. But not to fix the original problem.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140803/make-appbarlayout-respond-to-scrolling-in-webview) StackOverflow post which suggested extending WebView and implementing NestedScrollingChild as has been done [here (Apache2)](https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/takahirom/webview_in_coodinator_layout/NestedWebView.java).

This works perfectly. However, it is not a solution to the actual problem.

The layout now reads

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/browser_root"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/browser_loading_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


        <com.tpb.hn.story.NestedWebView
            android:id="@+id/browser_webview"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible">

        </com.tpb.hn.story.NestedWebView>



</LinearLayout>
```

The only change being adding the layout_behavior.

Answer (score 0):

i has same issue
and then i added code delayed handler

```
private void loadJavaScript(String script) {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                if (mWebView != null) {
                    mWebView.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
                    return;
                }
            }

            loadPage("javascript:" + script);
        }
    }, 500); //this 
}
```